Work place favouritism
This problems seems to be  ongoing. I recently joined a company, where my boss has the tendency of  hiring people only she knows. I got hired, probably because I was lucky.. But since day one, I am not getting "welcome" vibes from her. It looks like I was hired due to a panel decision. She has another person in the team, who she knows and goes above and beyond to praise him. She even recently made him present the work I did, which devastated me. How should I  handle such a situation?

You have three choices:

Do nothing, and be sad about it.
Do nothing, and don't be sad about it.
Start a discussion with your manager about her decision, why it was made and how it made you feel.

Of those, (2) is a possibility if you can manage it but (3) is probably the best route to happiness longer term - but go in with an open mind and not with an immediate accusations of favouritism as you have made in your question.

don't do 3 unless you are prepared to do nothing at home

@TigerGuy There's the right way to have that conversation and the wrong way to have that conversation. Assuming a reasonable manager, it should be possible to have a difficult conversation with them; if the manager is unreasonable, well, it probably doesn't matter too much what you do.

Cronyism is a fact of life in many companies. There isn't all that much you can really do about it.
The absolute best is to be more valuable and politely vocal about your accomplishments.

As in any company, you have to prove yourself by working hard and doing the best job possible.  Check your work before showing it to others and correct any errors you find. Thats if you want to stay there.
Perhaps, the other persons style is better for presentation than yours, through no fault of your own.

So manager's best mate can present your work without any mistakes.
